# Copy constructor twice

Tags: c++, dll, constructor, inline

I am having strange problem with c++. Dll A has class Cl with a lot of inlines in .h  (exported) and copy constructor in cpp (exported as well). Next the Cl.h is included in project B producing dll as well. After all, I use both dll in project C. But, linker complaints over redefinition of copy constrictor.

My question is why. Could B implement default copy constrictor silently?! What is even worth, when loading dynamically I have no errors at all, but default copy constructor is used. 
Finally, that happens only in release, but seemingly does not depend upon optimization settings.

I would appreciate any hint. How would you make it work like this if you would need it?

Code is currently quite long and I seem to be unable to reproduce the issue elsewhere.
Compiler is VS2010.

Comment: Hard to say: not much to go on here. Are you compiling for 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Could you write how to you use code from Cl.h?

Comment: Also try to add next line at the first line of the CI.h: #pragma once

Comment: 32 bit indeed. I do have if not Def/Def in the beginning of includes. Cl is in fact a storage, therefore constructors/data extraction is used.

Comment: Perhaps create some simple copy constructors to see what kind of errors that gives you?  It might point you in a new direction and help isolate the issue.

Comment: You can also look at your map file output to see what is being created as well, as a sanity check.

Comment: Most important for me is to understand why and where else this can happen. Is about large legacy project intensively used.

Comment: If I migrate copy constructor to inline it is used and issue is solved. But gives me no key why. ...